# uninstall the linux-image-x.x.x but update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.250-0404250-generic

Tags: boot, apt, kernel, dpkg

the /boots only has 200M so i tried to remove the unuse linux-image like

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-4.4.250*
```

and check

```
$ dpkg --list|grep linux-image
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-210-generic          4.4.0-210.242                                       amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-generic                    4.4.0.210.216                                       amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
$ dpkg --list|grep linux-headers
ii  linux-headers-4.4.0-210                4.4.0-210.242                                       all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.4.0
ii  linux-headers-4.4.0-210-generic        4.4.0-210.242                                       amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-generic                  4.4.0.210.216                                       amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers
```

but after i tried sudo apt-get it's shows still update initramfs of the version 4.4.250, the /boot full again:

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 248 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up linux-firmware (1.173.21) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.250-0404250-generic
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be opened: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_EGL.conf: No such file or directory

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure find 141 cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.250-0404250-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package linux-firmware (--configure):
 installed linux-firmware package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-firmware
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

i'm not sure what i left to do? how to release the space of /boot?
looking for any solution, i'll be appreciate very much

Comment: What OS & release are you using?  The 4.4 kernel hasn't been used by *standard* support releases of Ubuntu that are on-topic on this site for many years (please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

200 MiB is quite small. Keeping at most two kernels in `/boot` is already the most you should clean. Increasing the size of the /boot partition would be the best solution, but there are other ways to address it:

- Use a stronger compression than gzip (see initramfs.conf man page):

```
COMPRESS=xz
COMPRESSLEVEL=9
```

- Use `MODULES=dep` instead of the default `MODULES=most`. Note: This will make the installation less portable. So beware when changing the hardware or moving the disk into a new system.